# Concatenate 2 audio sources with OpenAL

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, c, openal

I'm using OpenAL as the sound engine for my iPhone game, but still learning how to use it. I managed to play sounds with it, however I'm in one point when I need to concatenate (not merge) 2 sound sources (same file in fact, so this needs no conversion I guess) and I'm stuck. Any help would totally be appreciated:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you landed on this: [OpenAL Programmers Guide](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Documentation/OpenAL_Programmers_Guide.pdf)

Try looking into [ExtAudioFile](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ExtAudioFile).

Comment: Yes I did had a look over OpenAL Programmers Guide, right now I'm trying to use alSourceQueueBuffers for this task, no success yet :(